# getting an empty array when res.json() in nodejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a code snippet that shows all the posts along with the posts' username and the users display picture (DP). The snippets working perfectly fine, the log output is perfect but, I am not able to post this as JSON object in response.

This is my code:

```
router.get('/get_posts',jwt, function(req,res){
    var send = [];

    post.find({}).populate({ path:'author', model: User }).exec(function(err,res){
    var send = [];
    if(err)
    {console.log(err,err.stack);}
    if(res){
          for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++)
    {
     send.push({username:res[i].author.username,dp:res[i].author.dp,subject:res[i].subject,Body:res[i].Body,nofppl:res[i].nofppl});
    }
    console.log(send);
      }
    });
    res.json(send);
    });
```

The log result is perfect:

```
[ 
 { 
  username: 'sonic',
  dp: '',
  subject: 'ckjndckldsnck',
  Body: 'xekjf ckjfcnkjfcnfrnrfncfjcfrjnfcjnccfr',
  nofppl: 25 
  },
 { 
  username: 'sonic',
  dp: '',
  subject: 'ckjndckldsnck',
  Body: 'xekjf ckjfcnkjfcnfrnrfncfjcfrjnfcjnccfr',
  nofppl: 25 
  },
  { 
  username: 'sonic',
  dp: '',
  subject: 'ckjndckldsnck',
  Body: 'xekjf ckjfcnkjfcnfrnrfncfjcfrjnfcjnccfr',
  nofppl: 25 
  }
 ]
```

(I just posted the same post 3 times, the snippet works, am not bale to just post this data in the response)

I am getting an empty array in response.

The response:

```
[]
```

So, kind of the array is getting thrown before all the objects are pushed into it, What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try given below code, It's should work, send is keyword in java script use other key to create array and you calling the global send array that's why u getting empty.

```
 router.get('/get_posts',jwt, function(req,res){
 var array = [];
  post.find({}).populate({ path:'author', model: User }).exec(function(err,result){
   if(err)
    {
     console.log(err,err.stack);
    }
 if(result){
  for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
    {
    array.push({
        username:result[i].author.username,
        dp:result[i].author.dp,
        subject:result[i].subject,
        Body:result[i].Body,
        nofppl:result[i].nofppl
    });
      }
    console.log(array);
    res.json(array);
     }
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an asynchronous call `post.find({})`.

So `res.json(send)` is called before the asynchronous callback which builds your json. This is why the result is empty.

You should do `res.json(xxx)` inside the exec function

Comment: now, i am getting "[ ]" in both console and HTTP result if, i write "res.json(send)" inside exec(), i think because it is asynchronous it's executing anything that takes lesser time. Still not getting what i want.

Answer (score 0):

May be problem with send variable and you returning json from out of scope and you have one extra closing braces. check carefully your code

```
post.find({}).populate({ path: 'author', model: User }).exec(function (err, res) {
    var data = [];
    if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack); }
    if (res) {
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
         data.push({ username: res[i].author.username, dp: res[i].author.dp, subject: res[i].subject, Body: res[i].Body, nofppl: res[i].nofppl });
        }
        res.json(data);
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes arise from mixing `res` variable names:

```
router.get('/get_posts',jwt, function(req,res){
  getData().then(res => {
     res.json({ res });
  })
});
```